# Desktop Internet traffic measurement software

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, monitoring

Can you recommend a *robust* Internet traffic measurement tool you had experience with?

Robustness is important because I've used a couple of such tools but ended up uninstalling them because of network connectivity problems they caused.

Thanks!

**Edit:** I don't have my own router, so I suppose SNMP-based software is not an option here.
A live indicator of overall Internet traffic (all but local network) would be just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [DU Meter](http://www.dumeter.com/).

Comment: Thanks! Looks like what I need. Will see if it is robust ;)

Comment: Dude loves robust stuff.

Comment: DU meter is awesome, better than NetLimiter!

Comment: Note: Cost for a home license is $22

Answer (score 4):

The question about how you intend to measure the internet traffic.  I will suggest a couple of options since I do not know your specific target scenario.

One decent internet monitoring tool is Snort (http://snort.org).  It provides nice intrusion detection and can monitor the traffic hitting the internet quite nicely.  Snort is great for intrussion detection but it is not so much a connectivity tool as it is a security tool. So this might not be the perfect tool for you.

Another good application that does this is MRTG...

MRTG is an excellent program that for stuff like monitoring your routers, switches etc. It is free and it has the ability to monitor a great many things.  It will connect to the SNMP port of your router and you should be able to get all kinds of useful data about your connection at that point.

http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/

Now if you are trying to monitor your internet connection to see who you are talking to, you can always use the "Netstat" command from the command line or you can use TCPView from sysinternals to show you visually what your system is talking to over the wire.

Comment: Perhaps update your other post with this more elaborate description?

Comment: A good suggestion.  I opted not to amend the other answer simply because he has stated very narrow requirements.  He only wishes to monitor uptime which is a different animal from taking a much closer look at the traffic itself.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! I should have put it in a more clear way in the question. The software may be useful for someone in with different needs.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

[Need Software to Monitor Internet Uptime](https://superuser.com/questions/13698/need-software-to-monitor-internet-uptime)

by Axxmasterr

> MRTG is an excellent program that does this. It is free and it has the ability to monitor a great many things.
>
> http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/
>
> Check it out! You will not be disappointed...

Comment: Haha nevermind: the master himself posted it already!

Answer (score 0):

NetLimiter has a good real-time display of upload/download speeds

Comment: Maybe it's been improved, but I remember having network connectivity issues after installing NetLimiter, so I had to uninstall it after spending some time to figure out its network driver was causing the issues.

Comment: Just tried out DUmeter. It's awesome, better than NetLimiter