# Free tool for monitoring Broadband usage on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet, monitoring, broadband

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Software to report internet traffic for home user](https://superuser.com/questions/107879/software-to-report-internet-traffic-for-home-user)
>   [Desktop Internet traffic measurement  software](https://superuser.com/questions/13912/desktop-internet-traffic-measurement-software)

I need a free tool ( non browser ) to monitor my broadband usage on Windows 7 since my ISP has placed a cap on monthly downloads.

I need a PC based solution since I use a USB router to connect to the internet.All other solutions I found were router/network based and also wasn't sure of all the freeware tools I found on Google to do this job.Need suggestions personal experiences.

Comment: Does only one device (you computer) access the internet?

Comment: Yes..My laptop uses this Tata Photon Plus USB Device