# Monitor and view contents of incoming and outgoing internet traffic in Windows

Tags: windows, firewall, network-monitoring, sniffing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software for measuring internet traffic?](https://superuser.com/questions/75083/software-for-measuring-internet-traffic)

In the Chrome developer tools, I can easily monitor traffic that comes into and out of the browser.

Is there a way to monitor this type of information coming from all of the other programs in windows?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question: "Software for measuring internet traffic?". I do not want to measure the traffic, I want to view its contents.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use  http://superuser.com/questions/107879/software-to-report-internet-traffic-for-home-user http://superuser.com/questions/13912/desktop-internet-traffic-measurement-software

Comment: Those are all mostly about measurement. The one that is not is about knowing which programs are accessing the internet. I need to view actual header data and contents. This is why I took the time to post a picture as well.

Answer (score 2):

To monitor arbitrary network traffic you need something like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).