# Internet Traffic Monitoring

Tags: networking, monitoring

I wonder if there is a software that can spy on other applications or programs that are running on my system (one PC) and tell me which programs sent what to the network and what they received. I am simply a dumb in this area of computer science, so I don't really know how the network actually works. All I know that my PC can send and receive packages through some part on motherboard. I just want to catch that packages and collect them just like the Process Monitor works for activities other than network.

If you can explain me all this mess and expand my vocabulary so I can talk on this topic with ease, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Desktop Internet traffic measurement software](https://superuser.com/questions/13912/desktop-internet-traffic-measurement-software)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to capture every traffic, you could use wireshark: https://www.wireshark.org/download.html

If you are interested in the processes and which ports they use, you could download TCPView from the Windows Sysinternals: https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx

In my opinion the TCPView is easier to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful software is [Currports](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) from Nirsoft